# How to remove element from list

Tags: python

```
A=[[1, 2, 3], [2, 0, 4], [3, 5, 6]] 
B=[[3, 5, 8], [1, 0, 2], [1, 4, 9]]
```

I want to remove element 0, 0 in A and B then do do scatter plot.

```
for i in range(3):
    plt.scatter(A[i], B[i])
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj Edited the lists for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a commercial on TV, but just *Pop and plot!*

```
A[0].pop(0)
B[0].pop(0)
```